# Is IE9 native mode same as IE9 standards mode

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I need definition of native mode.

Browser Mode: IE9 Document Mode: IE9 standards

is this native mode? I guess so.

Browser Mode: IE9 Document Mode: Quirks

is this native mode? I guess so.

Please help me here. Thanks

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/03/24/ie9-s-document-modes-and-javascript.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "native mode" is not one that we use for IE. Can you clarify where you found that reference?

Typically the most important thing to pay attention to is document mode. One interpretation of "native" could be the document mode that matches the version of the browser itself (i.e. the latest document mode, a.k.a. edge mode) but as mentioned previously we do not typically use that phrase.

Comment: Thanks Charles, this is very supportive.